# How to compare Google Appengine DateTime against a Date object in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am new to Google Appengine. In my application, the datastore entities store a java.util.Date object. I want to query the datastore to return all the entities before a particular time. My code for this is :

```
Date date = new Date();
Query<Event> query = ofy().load().type(Event.class).order("date");
query = query.filter("date <", date);
```

which upon execution, gives the error : `Invalid date/time format: Sat Apr 04 00:40:22 IST 2015`

If this format is invalid, which format do I need to use to query?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;

@Entity
public class EntityDate {
    public EntityDate() {
        // Objectify needed
    }

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Index
    public Date date;
}
```

and here the code which makes the query

```
Date date = new Date();

Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.ofy();
ObjectifyService.register(EntityDate.class);
EntityDate entityDate = new EntityDate();
entityDate.date = date;
ofy.save().entities(entityDate);

Query<EntityDate> ofyQuery = ofy.load().type(EntityDate.class).order("date");
ofyQuery = ofyQuery.filter("date <", date);
List<EntityDate> list = ofyQuery.list();

Logger.getLogger("EntityDate").info(list.toString());
```

The entities are correctly saved
[image]

and the query provides the 4 results

```
[EntityDate@6780874d, EntityDate@27330551, EntityDate@6a21cf2, EntityDate@7d1a5744]
```

The default `toString()` of the class is a bit ugly, but it makes the point about the query correctly executed.

Can you provide the source of your `Event` class and the continuation of your code which execute the query?

Comment: My entity class was very similar, just a POJO.

Still the querying wasn't working for me. So instead of trying the query with default date format, I tried SimpleDateFormat to get it into a different format and it worked!

Thank for you help though.

Comment: Are you formatting the date before the query or you are using the java.util.Date object directly?

Comment: Actually earlier I was trying to use a newly created java.util.Date object directly and was getting the error. So now I am formatting it before query and it works fine.

Comment: This is strange, my code works fine using directly the java.util.Date. Which version of Objectify are you using?

Comment: Objectify Version 5.0

Comment: And the code you provided is complete or just a part? The query execution is missing, which method do you use?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. This is just a part of the code. The whole code of the method I am using now is :

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date date = sdf.parse(fromDate); //fromDate is the parameter provided
Query<Event> query = ofy().load().type(Event.class).order("date");
query = query.filter("date >", date);
return query.list();

Comment: Have you tried my snippet (it is complete so it is a working code) in your project if it gets the same error?

Comment: No I just went ahead and used SimpleDateFormat. It worked so I didn't bother to change it.